# How do I change the code formatting?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736394/how-to-use-a-python-function-in-julia) where I used the Python tag. Nevertheless, my code is in Julia and the website formatted it automatically in Python.

How can I change that?